# T-SQL to PL-SQL - Using null and like in the same search, but only the null sentence is working

Tags: oracle, t-sql, plsql

I need to change some searches that are working on sql server to an oracle database.

In the query below, if the search is null, it returns all records, if the user searches for a specific name, returns only the name.

SQL SERVER:

```
   SELECT * FROM Person " +
                      "WHERE (@Nome IS NULL OR Nome LIKE @Nome + '%') " +
                      "ORDER BY [Nome] " +
                      "OFFSET " + pageSize * (pageNumber - 1) + " ROWS " +
                      "FETCH NEXT " + pageSize + " ROWS ONLY " +
                      " " +
                      "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Person " +
                      "WHERE (@Nome IS NULL OR Nome LIKE @Nome + '%') AND Ativo = 1";
```

By changing the query to pl / sql, I can bring up all the records, if no search is done, but when searching for a specific name, it is returning empty.

ORACLE:

```
SELECT * 
           FROM (
               SELECT ROWNUM rnum, b.* 
                   FROM (
                      SELECT * 
                          FROM Person 
                              WHERE (:Nome IS NULL OR NOME LIKE ':Nome%')
                            )b 
                    ) WHERE RNUM between :PageSize * (:PageNumber - 1) AND  (:PageSize * :PageNumber)";
```

How to return a specific or null name, and if possible ... how would I do to return the count of that search along with the query?

Comment: `NOME LIKE ':Nome%'` has the variable name in quotes. That would be like using `'@Nome%'` in SQL Server.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes, but I'm changing to Oracle, thats why im using " :Name"

Comment: Well, it seems quoting the variable name doesn’t work in either RDBMS, or in most programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CONCAT:

```
Nome LIKE :Nome || '%'
-- or
Nome LIKE CONCAT(:Nome, '%')
```